# Error Code 203 on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I keep getting this error

```
12-21 09:32AM 10.043 /matrix 500 334696ms 147411cpu_ms 147411api_cpu_ms 0kb AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)
0.1.0.2 - - [21/Dec/2010:09:37:44 -0800] "POST /matrix HTTP/1.1" 500 0 
 "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" 
"ms=334696 cpu_ms=147412 api_cpu_ms=147412 cpm_usd=4.096789 queue_name=matrix task_name=matrix17---2010-12-21---17-26-17-063849 pending_ms=7280 exit_code=203

W 12-21 09:37AM 44.688
A serious problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you should contact the App Engine team. (Error code 203)
```

I am running some tasks in the background which use datastore and memory intensively. I tried printing out the log which doesnt show up.
What does this error mean and how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You have probably hit the request time limit.

If you use the "logger" module then you should be able to see the print outs by clicking on login to appspot, click on "Logs" and set "Logs with minimum severity" to "Debug".

Comment: when Error code 203 is thrown, no logging information will be produced. Even your print out statements will be removed.

Comment: @Sam sorry but i can only give you some general suggestions as i do not know exactly what tasks are your application trying to perform.

1. split the job into smaller pieces
2. reduce database access (number of cells) as it takes time
3. optimize ur code (http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips)

Comment: @Sam - did you ever find ways to address that 203 problem? We get occasional bursts of 500 errors logged as INFO with the Error Code 203 like this: 2013-02-03 12:07:29.490
The process handling this request unexpectedly died. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. (Error code 203)

Comment: Hi, any clues on this?